# android terminal rm read-only file system

Tags: linux

I have odroid c2 with android installed and I am trying to install a wlan driver, but while compiling I get an read-only file system error.

```
make install

make -C /mnt/sdcard/Download/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux -f Makefile.6 install
make[1]: Entering directory '/storage/emulated/0/Download/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux'
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/etc/Wireless’: File exists
rm -rf /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA
rm: cannot remove '/etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/RT2870STA.dat': Read-only file system
make[1]: *** [Makefile.6:555: install] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/storage/emulated/0/Download/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux'
make: *** [Makefile:503: install] Error 2
```

Can somebody give me a hint how to solve it?

Comment: I don't know anything about the Odroid Android build, but many embedded Linux systems mount the root filesystem read-only. So the error you see might be what you should expect. Can you write _any_ file in `/etc`? If your root fileystem really is mounted read-only, you'll either have to find a way to remount it read-write, or modify the Makefile to write its files somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using an sd-card try mounting the file system as rw

```
sudo mount -rw /dev/DEVICE NAME
```

If that gives and error add a **-r** in there also and you could just try using

```
sudo mount -r /dev/DEVICE NAME
```

or

```
sudo chmod +x on the folder or file.
```